# How to setup efficient vscode ionic typescript workflow

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to reduce the amount of time wasted fiddling with tools but it seems an impossible task.

What I have:

- an Ionic project open in VSCode with cordova tools installed.
- proper js map files being created
- If I hit f5 I get a new chrome window and I will hit my break points in my typescript
- a tsconfig file telling typescript to watch for changes

My problems:

- The command window opened from code running tsc will get hung up without my clicking on it. So I never know if my js files are actually up to date.
- The command window opened from code running ionic serve will get hung up waiting for user input so sometimes live reload is working and sometimes not.
  -If I try and open tools in chrome when already attached in vscode  (to check if i'm actually debugging the latest) the vscode detaches and the chrome window closes.

What I want:
 to spend my time writing my code and not spinning in circles trying to keep everything else in this hodgepodge working long enough to accomplish something...

I want a live reload typescript debugging workflow that keeps a debugger attached as I make changes (preferably inside vs code but I could even suck it up and do it from chrome tools if it was stable.) can such a workflow be created?  Do you have one? What do you do to be efficient?

Comment: I'm running `ionic serve` in a seperate git bash, not from VS code and debug everything in Chrome. This does the job for me...